# Full embeddings of categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

By the book “a course in homological algebra”, by Hilton and Stammbach, on pages 74, 75, for abelian categories we have a full embedding theorem which as I understood, we can use this theorem to compute the limits and colimits of finite diagrams but not the infinite ones. My first question is that why it is true. More generally, if we have a full embedding of a category in another category, let’s say, we have two categories $C$ and $D$ and a functor $F:C\longrightarrow D$ which fully embedded $C$ in $D$, then is it true that the finite limits and finite colimits in $F(C)$, $F(C)$ as a category, are the same as the finite limits and finite colimits of our main diagram in $F(C)$ but as a diagram in $D$?
My second question is that why it is not true for the infinite case.

Comment: Freyd-Mitchell gives an exact embedding which is, by definition, a fully faithful functor preserving finite limits and colimits but not necessarily infinite ones. A fully faithful functor isn't guaranteed to preserve any limits or colimits, finite or infinite, in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so, what do we have here which guarantee that fully faithful functor preserves finite limits and colimits? I mean what is special for abelian categories or for that full embedding theorem?

Comment: It is the exactness that is special,